# Error while creating tables dynamically in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe which I want to filter and create tables based on years in this case. I have 4 years now.So I would like to create 4 new tables and show them seperately on the shiny app.I do get the part of looping and pass the filter variables but how can that create 4 new tables and show them in the UI. I am able to get dynamic tabpanels but the library(shiny)

```
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = "tab",
              menuItem("1", tabName = "1")
  )
)
body <-   ## Body content
  dashboardBody(box(
    uiOutput('mytabs')
    ))

ui <-   dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Scorecard"),
                      sidebar,
                      body)

# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  df <- data.frame(structure(list(`Mazda` = c(21000,20000,21500,24000), `Honda` = c(21500,20500,22000,24500)
                                  ,  Sales = c(2017,2015,2016,2014)
                                  )
                             , class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)))
  toAdd <- as.vector(df$Sales)

  for(i in length(toAdd)){
    print(length(toAdd))
  output[[paste0("datatable_",i)]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
   df %>% filter(Sales == toAdd[i])
  })
#}
 # for(i in 1:length(toAdd)){

  output$mytabs <- renderUI({
    nTabs = length(toAdd)
    # create tabPanel with datatable in it
    myTabs = lapply(seq_len(nTabs), function(i) {
      tabPanel(paste0("dataset_",toAdd[i]),
               DT::dataTableOutput(paste0("datatable_",i))
      )
    })

    do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)

  })
}
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `for(i in length(toAdd))` should be `for(i in 1:length(toAdd))`, or `for(i in seq_along(toAdd))`.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent. But now it filters only for `2014` and not any other values in the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `local`, and don't put `renderUI` inside the loop:

```
  for(i in 1:length(toAdd)){
    local({
      ii <- i
      output[[paste0("datatable_",ii)]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
        df %>% filter(Sales == toAdd[ii])
      })
    })
  }

  output$mytabs <- renderUI({
    nTabs = length(toAdd)
    # create tabPanel with datatable in it
    myTabs = lapply(seq_len(nTabs), function(i) {
      tabPanel(paste0("dataset_",toAdd[i]),
               DT::dataTableOutput(paste0("datatable_",i))
      )
    })
    do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
  })
```