# Dynamically add plot with title in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to dinamically generate plots using shiny, but each plot with a different title.

I have tried using the for bucle to generate n number of plots and show them using an observeEvent, but this is not working for me, as the main of the plot is ignored.

To ensure that each plot has its own main title, what I do is to store the title into a data.frame and access to it from the plot.

Here the code:

```
    library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    textInput("title","Title",""),
    actionButton("generate","Plot"),
    div(class="aux",style="width:300px;height:200px")

)


server <- function(input,output){

    observeEvent(input$generate,{
                  insertUI(
                      selector= ".aux",
                      where="beforeBegin",
                      ui = plotOutput(paste0("plot",input$generate))

                  )

        if(input$generate == 1){

            data <<- data.frame(title = input$title)
        }else{
            aux <- data.frame(title=input$title)
            data <<- rbind(data,aux)

        }   


    })

    for(i in 1:10){

        output[[paste0("plot",i)]] <- renderPlot(
            plot(rnorm(100),main=data[i,"title"])

        )


    }



}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

This other code do what I really want to do, but it is not good programing to declare manually the plots:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    textInput("title","Title",""),
    actionButton("generate","Plot"),
    div(class="aux",style="width:300px;height:200px")

)


server <- function(input,output){

    observeEvent(input$generate,{
                  insertUI(
                      selector= ".aux",
                      where="beforeBegin",
                      ui = plotOutput(paste0("plot",input$generate))

                  )

        if(input$generate == 1){

            data <<- data.frame(title = input$title)
        }else{
            aux <- data.frame(title=input$title)
            data <<- rbind(data,aux)

        }   


    })



        output$plot1 <- renderPlot(
            plot(rnorm(100),main=data[1,"title"])
        )
        output$plot2 <-    output$plot1 <- renderPlot(
            plot(rnorm(100),main=data[2,"title"])
        )





}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**EDITED**:

Using the recomendations of Stephane Laurent, I have put the insertUI and output[[plot]] inside the observeEvent, but this not solves the issue to be able to edit the plot title changing the data.frame title. Here the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6,
  textInput("title","Title",""),
  actionButton("generate","Plot"),
  div(id="aux")),
  column(6,
  textInput("newt","New title",""),
  selectInput("row","Row",choices=c(1:10)),
  actionButton("change","Change title"))


)


server <- function(input,output){
  observeEvent(input$change,{
    df$title <<- as.character(df$title)
    df[input$row,"title"]<-input$newt 


  })
  k <- 0
  observeEvent(input$generate, {
    insertUI(
      selector= "#aux",
      where="beforeBegin",
      ui = plotOutput(paste0("plot",input$generate))
    )
    k <- k + input$generate
    if(input$generate==1){
      df <<- data.frame(title = input$title)
      df$title <<- as.character(df$title)

    }else{

      aux <- data.frame(title = input$title)
      df <<- rbind(df,aux)
      df$title <<- as.character(df$title)
    }


    output[[paste0("plot",input$generate)]] <- renderPlot(
      plot(rnorm(100), main = df[k,"title"])      
    )









  })  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I think you have to use `local`, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414001/error-while-creating-tables-dynamically-in-r-shiny/52414252#52414252

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with that solution is that all the plots are generated when you click on generate plot. What I want is that the plot will be added only one per click.

Comment: So why are you doing a loop ?

Comment: Because the loop only generates the plots but not show them, and only when I click on generate Plot, the insertUI inserts the plots. The issue is that this plots do not get the value of the title from the data.frame dinamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `renderPlot` inside the observer:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  textInput("title","Title",""),
  actionButton("generate","Plot"),
  div(id="aux")

)


server <- function(input,output){

  observeEvent(input$generate, {
    insertUI(
      selector= "#aux",
      where="beforeBegin",
      ui = plotOutput(paste0("plot",input$generate))
    )

    output[[paste0("plot",input$generate)]] <- renderPlot(
      plot(rnorm(100), main = isolate(input$title))      
    )
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

## EDIT

Solution for the edited question:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  column(6,
         textInput("title","Title",""),
         actionButton("generate","Plot"),
         div(id="aux")),
  column(6,
         textInput("newt","New title",""),
         selectInput("row","Row",choices=c(1:10)),
         actionButton("change","Change title"))  
)    

server <- function(input,output){

  titles <- reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$change, {
    titles[[input$row]] <- input$newt
  })

  values <- replicate(10, rnorm(100))

  for(i in 1:10){
    local({
      ii <- i
      output[[paste0("plot",ii)]] <- renderPlot(
        plot(values[,ii], main = titles[[as.character(ii)]])
      )
    })
  }

  observeEvent(input$generate, {
    titles[[as.character(input$generate)]] <- input$title
    insertUI(
      selector = "#aux",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = plotOutput(paste0("plot",input$generate))
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: It works, and is a very good aproximation, but I need to store the title in a data.frame, so if you change the data.frame value the title will change. I have include in the observeEvent the generation of the data.frame and change the main=isolate... by main=df[input$generate,"title"], but it does not work